# How can I start creating my own pixel or vector art graphics for my game?

Tags: vector, line-art, pixel-art

I am making a game with Adobe Flash. I have completed the mechanics for the game, and I am now trying to make the graphics for it. The game is a simple top down shooter.

I am not much of an artist but more of a decent programmer. So I have played games on various sites like armorgames.com, mofunzone.com etc. Although I have tried a lot of [pixel art tutorials like these ones](http://garmahis.com/tutorials/pixel-art-tutorials/), I can't help but notice that the graphics on armorgames.com and such have vector like graphics that obviously rasterised for performance.

I want to know if there any good recommended steps for creating this sort of art.

Comment: I think you'd be better off picking a vector application and then simply learning that application for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience (might not apply to other people, though) I can tell you **pixel art** is one of the most difficult types of digital art. Perfecting a design is, in most cases, removing every unnecessary element possible, until you have the simplest form of expression for your idea. And expressing something in a few pixels is an herculean task!

Unless you are interested in adding digital design / art to you pool of skills, I'd consider maybe looking for a **partner** that can do the graphic part, or buying some nice **stock vectors** and working around those. Illustration is fascinating, but like everything, it takes time. Adding to the 'perfecting' of what you will create, you still need to learn the **tools** to do it, so the curve can be quite steep at first. And if someone has done it already, and successfully, you could be investing that extra time you'd spend in graphics, in developing your game more.

Having said that, if you are familiar with the drawing tools Flash comes with, it might be a bit easier. I'd recommend you start by choosing a style you like (from other games for example) and try to imitate - without stealing, of course ;) - what they look like. Once you got the basics you can work on finding your own style.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have Flash I would advise learning how to use [Illustrator](http://layersmagazine.com/category/illustrator).  A fairly old article over at [Spoon](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/50-illustrator-tutorials-every-designer-should-see) may also help you with Illustrator, if not it may be an excellent read to get you started.  I did have to take a class in Flash a long time ago and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240520580) was our book which we created a game from.